# Different answers for probability density function and cumulative density function

Tags: probability, integration

I have a function $f(x)=2ae^{-ax}(1-e^{-ax})$, for $x>0, a>0$. This is a pdf. I need to find $P(X>1)$. I have done all my work in such a way that I should get the same answer whether I use the pdf or the cdf to find this probability. However, I'm getting different answers. Can someone please help me?

**My attempt:**

(using pdf) $P(X>1)=\int_1^{\infty}2ae^{-ax}(1-e^{-ax})dx = 2e^{-a}-e^{-2a}$ 
(using cdf) $P(X>1)= 1-P(X\leq 1) = 1 - (F_X(1)) = 1-(e^{-ax}(e^{-ax}-2))|_{x=1}=1-2e^{-a}-e^{-2a}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "find probabilities" using the pdf, and in fact in what you write, actually you do *not* use the pdf to find probabilities. Your first calculation is correct, but essentially you do not "use the pdf", since you integrate it, and hence you use the cdf.

Your second calculation is wrong because you use the pdf expression in place of the cdf:

$$1- F_X(1) = 1- \int_0^{1}2ae^{-ax}(1-e^{-ax})dx $$

is the correct expression. You can find the cdf by calculating

$$F_X(x) = \int_0^{x}2ae^{-az}(1-e^{-az})dz$$